# PHP Debugging with Breakpoints - case studies, examples..?

Tags: php, debugging, breakpoints

I'd really like to get deeper into my php scripts and use things like breakpoints, as I'm doing with JS with firebug.

I'd like to know more about what techniques people use, and some solid examples of how to debug with breakpoints a php project.

Thing's I'd like to be able to see..

- Properties of objects
- Class hierarchies.. where objects are coming from, file names etc.. (useful in ZF/Magento)
- Variables, types, content..
- headers, post data, get data, session data, cookies..
- Network / filesystem status..

I know a lot of this can be done with logging and print_r/vardump etc, but its a bit raw.. and I'd like to be able to use a "continue"/"step-over" etc command on code after hitting a breakpoint, like with firebug.

from php.ini:

```
zend_extension_ts = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.2-vc6.dll;
xdebug.remote_enable=On;
xdebug.remote_host="localhost";
xdebug.remote_port=9000;
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp";
```

Comment: please see stackoverflow.com/questions/30124782/debug-project-in-phpstorm , it answers the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[xdebug + remote debugging + one of the supported clients](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Comment: xdebug looks excellent, along with the windows client. I'm not using one of the supported IDEs (I use E almost exclusively), though.

Comment: Great, thanks. For reference, this is useful overview: http://brownsofa.org/blog/archives/99

Comment: With this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug), you can even use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)!

Answer (score 3):

Use XDebug, it does most of what you require (not network/filesystem), and with it you can debug from eclipse, zend studio, pdt, or even notepad++

I keep debugging again and again when dealing with Magento, and it is super useful in this case, since Magento's function call stack is very deep.

Comment: As on Wrikken's answer, xdebug looks great, thanks for the tip. I'd still like to see some case studies too!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is interpreted and server side scripting language. So, there are only few editors that supports the break point in PHP. And if you are doing the server side scripting then there is no way to debug your script using break points.

However if you are planning to have basic scripting & debugging then you can go with http://www.firephp.org/. Also if you use Zend Studio editor then you will have many options on hand for debugging your script. Zend Studio supports the break point, run & debug options.

I prefer to log the execution of my script in file.

Thanks

Comment: Read stackoverflow.com/questions/30124782/debug-project-in-phpstorm