# GDB: Setting a Breakpoint on Non-Source File

Tags: gdb

If I attached GDB to the httpd process and wanted to set a breakpoint on a file in the htdocs folder, ie when 'echo' is called on line 3 of example.php, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a Breakpoint on Echo in GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059688/setting-a-breakpoint-on-echo-in-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GDB to debug a PHP program (`example.php`). See [PHP Debugging with Breakpoints - case studies, examples..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717136/php-debugging-with-breakpoints-case-studies-examples) on how to setup PHP remote debugging with the `xdebug2` module.

HINT: inserting xdebug_break() right before the `echo` line in `example.php` is an easy way to set the break point.

Please tag PHP development questions with php instead of gdb.